# Complete list of Typescript error codes and their fixes

Tags: typescript

In Typescript, where do I find a complete reference of all error codes and their fixes.

My usecase is that I often see errors when compiling. for example:

```
data_loader_service.ts(10,13): error TS1005: '=>' expected.
data_loader_service.ts(10,24): error TS1144: '{' or ';' expected.
data_loader_service.ts(10,27): error TS1068: Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.
data_loader_service.ts(14,1): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
```

I am looking for a place where I can easily lookup the error codes, e.g. TS1068 and read about the typical error and the typical fixes.

I am inspired by, for instance Jscs, which give nice overviews of all potential error codes.

Example from Jscs: http://jscs.info/rules

I am accepting responses that refer to either sourcecode or a finer webpage like the jscs example.

I expect you post an answer regarding the new Typescript (currently 1.6 is the most recent).

Comment: in `tsc.js`, `tsserver.js`, `typescript.js` and `typescriptServices.js`, a variable `ts.Diagnostics` is initialized with a dictionary of all the error codes. Falls short of a documentation I am afraid

Comment: @BGR feel free to provide as an aswer with links, so I can vote, please :)

Comment: @ Jesper Rønn-Jensen - Done :). Le me know if you want me to copy paste the list of codes in the response for easier reference

Comment: @BGR if you can at least provide some links to the specific source code files. I failed to find them myself. I believe the specific links will be really helpful for other readers.

Comment: Done - see edit in answer

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Looking at the 1.6.2 sources of the compiler, `tsc.js`, `tsserver.js`, `typescript.js` and `typescriptServices.js`, a variable called `ts.Diagnostics` is initialized with a dictionary of all the error codes.

List of codes and definitions of 1.6.2 (unfortunately ugly formatted): https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v1.6.2/src/compiler/diagnosticInformationMap.generated.ts

A slightly prettier format is available:
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v1.6.2/src/compiler/diagnosticMessages.json

**EDIT**

Link to 1.8.5 errors: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v1.8.5/src/compiler/diagnosticMessages.json

Comment: In that 2nd link , There are all kinds are error's are there...Like that is there any site's which is having solution that error's ?

Comment: 2.7.2 errors: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v2.7.2/src/compiler/diagnosticMessages.json

Comment: Here's a list of compiler options that affect and/or turn off many of the errors: https://www.typescriptlang.org/v2/en/tsconfig -- the page says the url may change, however.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a script to export a simple reference table from official typescript repo:

```
$ curl -sL https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/raw/v4.7.3/src/compiler/diagnosticMessages.json | jq -r 'to_entries[]|"TS\(.value.code): \(.key)"'
```

Output:

```
TS1002: Unterminated string literal.
TS1003: Identifier expected.
TS1005: '{0}' expected.
TS1006: A file cannot have a reference to itself.
TS1007: The parser expected to find a '{1}' to match the '{0}' token here.
TS1009: Trailing comma not allowed.
TS1010: '*/' expected.
TS1011: An element access expression should take an argument.
TS1012: Unexpected token.
TS1013: A rest parameter or binding pattern may not have a trailing comma.
TS1014: A rest parameter must be last in a parameter list.
TS1015: Parameter cannot have question mark and initializer.
TS1016: A required parameter cannot follow an optional parameter.
TS1017: An index signature cannot have a rest parameter.
TS1018: An index signature parameter cannot have an accessibility modifier.
TS1019: An index signature parameter cannot have a question mark.
TS1020: An index signature parameter cannot have an initializer.
...
TS18012: '#constructor' is a reserved word.
TS18013: Property '{0}' is not accessible outside class '{1}' because it has a private identifier.
TS18014: The property '{0}' cannot be accessed on type '{1}' within this class because it is shadowed by another private identifier with the same spelling.
TS18015: Property '{0}' in type '{1}' refers to a different member that cannot be accessed from within type '{2}'.
TS18016: Private identifiers are not allowed outside class bodies.
TS18017: The shadowing declaration of '{0}' is defined here
TS18018: The declaration of '{0}' that you probably intended to use is defined here
TS18019: '{0}' modifier cannot be used with a private identifier.
TS18024: An enum member cannot be named with a private identifier.
TS18026: '#!' can only be used at the start of a file.
TS18027: Compiler reserves name '{0}' when emitting private identifier downlevel.
TS18028: Private identifiers are only available when targeting ECMAScript 2015 and higher.
TS18029: Private identifiers are not allowed in variable declarations.
TS18030: An optional chain cannot contain private identifiers.
TS18031: The intersection '{0}' was reduced to 'never' because property '{1}' has conflicting types in some constituents.
TS18032: The intersection '{0}' was reduced to 'never' because property '{1}' exists in multiple constituents and is private in some.
TS18033: Only numeric enums can have computed members, but this expression has type '{0}'. If you do not need exhaustiveness checks, consider using an object literal instead.
TS18034: Specify the JSX fragment factory function to use when targeting 'react' JSX emit with 'jsxFactory' compiler option is specified, e.g. 'Fragment'.
TS18035: Invalid value for 'jsxFragmentFactory'. '{0}' is not a valid identifier or qualified-name.
TS18036: Class decorators can't be used with static private identifier. Consider removing the experimental decorator.
TS18037: Await expression cannot be used inside a class static block.
TS18038: 'For await' loops cannot be used inside a class static block.
TS18039: Invalid use of '{0}'. It cannot be used inside a class static block.
TS18041: A 'return' statement cannot be used inside a class static block.
```

Full result can be found [here](https://bafkreigb7rjyzbotvcy2jbbeaviyv33q5olmqkzdzizltzrxt4t47zk3i4.ipfs.dweb.link).