# Connecting typescript errors to their associated compiler options (tsconfig.json)

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, tsc

**How can I find out which compiler option is associated with a given Typescript error?**

I'm using Typescript in VSCode, and Typescript frequently points out problems, like `initializer provides no value for this binding element`

(Please note this is a warning generated by Typescript, not TSLint).

In `tsconfig.json`, I can turn off specific warnings, such as

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "noImplicitAny": false,
  "strictPropertyInitialization": false
}
```

But as far as I can tell, there's no way to find out which compiler option is associated with which error.

**Clues so far, but no solution:**

This SO post, [Complete list of Typescript error codes and their fixes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33410124/complete-list-of-typescript-error-codes-and-their-fixes), provides a list of messages, but not with which compiler option en/disables the message.

And unfortunately, the names of the compiler options do not mimic the wording of the errors, so you can't find the error via simple intellisense within `tsconfig.json`.

Additionally, the official docs seem not to provide such an error-to-option mapping, either: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html , https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html .

So, just to restate the question: how can I find out which compiler option to turn off to silence a given error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a 1:1 (or 1:n or n:1) correspondence between error messages and compiler settings, and the vast majority of errors cannot be turned off with any compiler option. Many compiler options change *behavior* in a way that mean you can't reliably say what would have happened counterfactually with some other set of options.

For the error messages that do have a corresponding flag, the error text usually hints at it

- `"x" implicitly has type 'any'` ▶ `noImplicitAny`
- `Unreachable code detected` ▶ `allowUnreachableCode`
- `Unused label detected` ▶ `allowUnusedLabels`
- `"x" is possibly "null"` ▶ `strictNullChecks`
- `Local "x" is unused` ▶ `noUnusedLocals`

etc